# Get json data in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview

HOW CAN GET launch_failure_details IN THIS CODE https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches .

THERE ARE JUST 5 launch_failure_details and ı display every entity but launch_failure_details is not. How can ı control this entity?

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] of the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are some strategies.

1. Initial all the data in advance 
   (So the data which is lacked could have a initial value)

   ```
   public class Person {
      private int height=0;
      private int weight=0;
      private int year = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Check the data is null or not before you use it